# manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()) very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net application hosted on goDaddy using SQL server as a back end.
I am using asp.net authentication to log in.
I am calling the following in order to get the properties of the user.

```
UserManager manager = new UserManager();
var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

the above line runs VERY slow. What could be the cause?

Comment: When you say that it runs slowly - how slow?  How does it compare with database access in other areas of your application?

Comment: Are you using EF with ASP.net Identity?  If you have written your own implementation using ADO.Net or an ORM that doesn't support lazy loading support and caching. Then it can be slow.  Some simple request can create a few unexpected round trips to the database.  See https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/discussions/561828 for more details.

Comment: It takes about 43 seconds for the page to load. when I step thru the debugger I see that the above line of code is the bottle neck. After this line of code executes, database access is very quick. I am using an asp.net login control in my site.master and I used all the default settings from asp.net identity - nothing fancy. If I close my browser and then within a few minutes open the browser again it connects quickly so I feel like it has something to do with setting up the session.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET application is probably running under ASPNET or Network Service instead of a domain user. Based on current situation, I suggest you impersonation first. You can enable it in web.config like this:

Consider the identities you are using and the way that you flow identity through your application. To access downstream resources, you can use the ASP.NET process identity. Or, you can enable impersonation and flow the identity of the original caller. If you connect to Microsoft SQL Server, you can also use SQL authentication. When you connect to a shared resource, such as a database, by using a single identity, you benefit from connection pooling. Connection pooling significantly increases scalability.

Comment: Consider the identities you are using and the way that you flow identity through your application. To access downstream resources, you can use the ASP.NET process identity. Or, you can enable impersonation and flow the identity of the original caller. If you connect to Microsoft SQL Server, you can also use SQL authentication. When you connect to a shared resource, such as a database, by using a single identity, you benefit from connection pooling. Connection pooling significantly increases scalability.  Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549.aspx

Comment: Icaro Camelo I am going to read the link that you sent about Improving ASP.NET Performance later. I will let you know if it is helpful.

Comment: Icaro Camelo  is what you wrote above about enabling impersonation relevant on shared hosting? I am not sure if I really understand what you are talking about. Thanks.